# Grub Rescue Mode - /boot/grub directory does not exist

Tags: ubuntu, boot, grub, boot-loader

I have gone through a lot of questions and answers related to `grub rescue` but I am having a different problem which I am not able to understand.

As per some of the answers, I tried following steps to resolve  this problem -

1. First of all I used `ls` command to get all the partitions which in my case were **`(hd0)`, `(hd0,msdos5)`, `(hdo,msdos1)`, `(hd1)` & `(hd1,msdos1)`**
2. Out of the above 5 partitions, I got **`Filesystem is ext2`** message for **`(hd0,msdos1)`** drive.
3. As per some of the answers provided in [ask ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119597/grub-rescue-error-unknown-filesystem) & [stack exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/70538/grub-error-file-grub-i386-pc-normal-mod-not-found) I tried to set the **`root`** & **`prefix`** using  **`(hd0,msdos1)`** drive (which I found using `ls` command)
4. **While setting `prefix` I realised that the `/boot/grub` directory does not exist in selected drive `(hd0,msdos1)`.**
5. As a result of this when I try to fire **`insmod normal`** command, grub rescue gives an error saying **`/boot/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod` not found**
6. *Apart from this, I tried using bootable USB drive with ubuntu 14, 16, 17, 18 & even windows OS but I always ended up in grub rescue window.*

This leaves me with following questions -

1. Am I setting a wrong drive as root drive (provided this is the only ext2 drive among 5 enlisted drives) ?
2. Is there a way of including the **`/boot/grub`** folder in the root directory so that I can run **`insmod normal** command ?

Answer (score 1):

As the boot partition is mounted on on top of `/boot` once the system boots, you wont find there `/boot/grub`.

The directory you are searching is `/grub` in the `boot` partition.

As for mounting a full system, you will have to mount the `/` first, then `/boot` on top of it.

Actually, if you are in a live DVD of the same architecture, you often mount:

```
/mnt -> root partition
/mnt/boot -> boot partition
/mnt/proc /proc
/mnt/sys /sys
/mnt/dev /dev
```

And then do a `chroot /mnt`

As for loading kernel modules, I would load them from the live booting system.

Answer (score 0):

```
ls (hdo,msdos1)
```

You said this gives Filesystem is ext2.

```
set boot=(hdo,msdos1)  
set prefix=(hdo,msdos1)/boot/grub
insmod normal
normal
```

Then boot into kali open terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall grub-pc
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
sudo update-initramfs -u
sudo update-grub
```